# infinite recursion with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, recursion

I have an input field where user enters the address. Google Maps API autocompletes it, and subsequently repositions map marker and is supposed to move the map to that location.

```
var map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(45.815015, 15.981912);
var marker;
var map;
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: map_location
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: map_location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
        document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value = this.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("long_hidden").value = this.getPosition().lng();
    });

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('autocomplete'), 
        {types: ['geocode']});

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("long_hidden").value)
        );
        marker.setPosition(map_location);
        map.panTo(map_location);
  });
}
```

The last line of code causes infinite recursion. I also tried `.setCenter`. Firefox traced recursion to maps.gstatic.com script which keeps calling its own two functions.

What is causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Didn't setCenter work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up the lat_hidden and long_hidden fields on the `place_changed` event.  So this code doesn't create a valid `google.maps.LatLng()`:

```
    map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value),
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("long_hidden").value)
    );
```

working code snippet:

```js
var map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(45.815015, 15.981912);
var marker;
var map;
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: map_location
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: map_location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("long_hidden").value = this.getPosition().lng();
  });

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("long_hidden").value = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
    map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat_hidden").value),
      parseFloat(document.getElementById("long_hidden").value)
    );
    marker.setPosition(map_location);
    map.panTo(map_location);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="lat_hidden" />
<input id="long_hidden" />
<input id="autocomplete" />
```